# Spring Scheduled bean with cron expression runs too frequently

Tags: spring, cron

I have a bean thats's defined:

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class ScheduledService {


   private final MyService myService;

   @Scheduled(cron = "${cron.expression}")
   @Override
   public void performCheck() {
       myService.foo();
   }
}
```

In the properties file the cron expression looks like this:

```
cron.expression = 0 0 7 * * *
```

I expected the task to run every day at 7AM. But it runs a few times a day, with uneven and non-consistent time intervals.

I'm not sure what's wrong with this configuration. I double and triple checked, but still - it continues to fire too often.

Comment: is your spel cron.expression is equal to oribi.uninstall-script-domain.cron?

Comment: you should have the "oribi.uninstall-script-domain.cron" in the scheduled annotation

Comment: @SangamBelose - Sorry, my bad. I meant to change the spel expression in both places to be `cron.expression` and not the original flag name. Fixed the question now.